# Docusign iOS SDK - Interactive PDF with checkbox and e-sign option

Tags: docusignapi

I want to create following use case using DocuSign iOS SDK.

Create PDF on iPhone app - with text and interactive fields like checkbox, sign and comments field.However not sure how to add them.

Is there any tutorial or document reference available which demonstrate how we can add interactive fields into PDF using DocuSign iOS SDK? I read about anchorTag but it seems to be available via REST/SOAP API.

Thanks!

Comment: After digging more into DocuSign IOS SDK, it seems there are options to prefill PDF document before sending it for signing. Anyone has more informations, please provide.